# SQL compare entire rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, compare, rows

In SQL server 2008 I have some huge tables (200-300+ cols). Every day we run a batch job generating a new table with timestamp appended to the name of the table.

The the tables have no PK.

I would like a generic way to compare 2 rows from two tables. Showing which cols having different values is sufficient, but showing the values would be perfect.

Thanks a lot

Thanks for the answers. I ended up writing my own C# tool to do the job - as I'm not allowed to install 3rd party software in my company.

Comment: If the table has no PK then how do you know which 2 rows to be comparing?

Comment: You can use [except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to find rows from table1 which do not have a match in table2.

Comment: Martin: I combine several cols to get a unique key
Nikola: Thanks, but I need to know the difference is, not that there are diffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools that do this for you.

My favorite is [Red Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/index-b?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqlcompare&gclid=CLOM5eu3qrACFYuc7QodFSaQTg).

If you don't have the money use the open source solutions. There are several

[DB Compare](http://dbcompare.codeplex.com/)

[OpenDBDiff](http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create RPT files from SELECT queries then use Beyond Compare to see the differences.

Also, red-gate has some tools to compare database tables, but I think they're expensive.